# Get values from Object

Tags: php

I was searching for Recursive way of listing all the files in a directory and subdirectories then I cam across this [Comment](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#85805) on PHP Documentation. This is the first time am seeing something as such hope someone can help me out.

**Object**

```
object(SplFileInfo)#6 (2) {
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(75) "D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\example/uploads\example.mp3"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(34) "example.mp3"
}
```

From that Object I need the "***fileName***" value.

Comment: Did you at all look into the docs for SplFileInfo http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getfilename.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your example, you can see that pathName and fileName are tagged as private that is to say you can access/modify their value outside of the class in a direct way. You can't do :

```
echo $obj->pathName;
```

All you can do is using accessors such as getPathName(), setPathName($name) which will be defined in the class scope so you can retrieve and modify data. As simple as that. So you're more likely to do :

```
echo $obj->getPathName();
```

For more details, have a look at : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29